# How to install a python package manually in centos red-had?

Tags: python, graph, neo4j, package

I need to install the package "graph" in python 2.6.6 to use it with `neo4j`.Is there a command I can execute to do that?

Comment: You can install pip first, then use use pip to install packages.
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/debian-ubuntu-centos-rhel-linux-install-pipclient/ - this may help you to install python packages.

Answer (score 0):

First you should download the Python package,  Explode it, you will see a file named 'setup.py'. And open the terminal in this folder. execute this command'python setup.py install' Or you also can simply use pip.